# Returning a String Array in Outmail.body

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the already known Subroutine to send a warning email to outlook whenever a condition is met.

In the routine I define an string array under the name DatePassed in which I store some dynamical values and I intent to return it's content in the Subject of the email.

The problem is that I don't know how exactly to handle DatePassed so to return me the whole array not just the first element.

How would I do this?

```
 Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()

      Dim OutApp As Object
      Dim OutMail As Object

      Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

      On Error Resume Next

      Dim DatePassed(100) As Variant
      Dim i As Integer
      For i = 6 To 13
           If Cells(i, 1) < Date Then
             DatePassed(i - 6) = Cells(i, 2)
           End If
      Next i

      With OutMail
          .To = "Joerge@Johnson.com"
          .CC = "James@Johnson.com"
          .BCC = ""
          .Subject = "Unmanaged Clients"
          .Body = DataPassed
          .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
          .Send
      End With
      On Error GoTo 0

      Set OutMail = Nothing
      Set OutApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

I have just added a `Loop` to run through the `Array` and stored it as a string which then gets assigned to the `.Body`

```
 Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()

      Dim OutApp As Object
      Dim OutMail As Object

      Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

      On Error Resume Next

      Dim DatePassed(100) As Variant
      Dim i As Integer
      For i = 6 To 13
           If Cells(i, 1) < Date Then
             DatePassed(i - 6) = Cells(i, 2)
           End If
      Next i

      '=================================================
      'New Section

      Dim DataPassedElementReference As Long
      Dim DataPassedString As String

      DataPassedString = ""

      'Using 100 as this is waht you used to define the array
      For DataPassedElementReference = 1 To 100

           DataPassedString = DataPassedString & DataPassed(DataPassedElementReference) & " "

      Next DataPassedElementReference
      '=================================================

      With OutMail
          .To = "Joerge@Johnson.com"
          .CC = "James@Johnson.com"
          .BCC = ""
          .Subject = "Unmanaged Clients"
          'Note the difference here
          '.Body = DataPassed
          .Body = DataPassedString
          .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
          .Send
      End With
      On Error GoTo 0

      Set OutMail = Nothing
      Set OutApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: @user3333331 remember to mark the chosen answer to be the correct answer and to up vote the answer as well.Also you don't need to Dim `DatePassed (100)` if you only using 7 elements of the array then only Dim it as required. Or do you need the 0 to 6 elements free in the array? Not sure what you refering to with the embedding but you could use `If Cells(i, 1) < Date Then DatePassed(i - 6) = Cells(i, 2)`